# selection sort output is not correct

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to implement selection sort in C++. I do not know what I did wrong in this code but the result is not sorted correctly.
Please let me know what I did wrong. Thank you for your help.

output result:
`23  31  4  89  2  8  10  11`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printElement(int arr[],int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      cout << arr[i] << "  ";            
}


// arr[] = {31, 23, 4, 89, 2, 8, 10, 11}
void selectionSort(int arr[], int size)
{     
   int i, j, min, min_id,  tmp;

   for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
       min = arr[i];
       for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
           if (arr[j] < min){
                min = arr[j];
                min_id = j;   
           } 
           tmp = arr[i]; //tmp = min; - this is wrong by msl
           arr[i] = arr[min_id]; //min = arr[min_id]; this is wrong by msl
           arr[min_id] = tmp;   
       }   
       printElement(arr, size); 
       cout << endl;  
   }  
}


int main()
{
    int size = 8;
    int arr[] = {31, 23, 4, 89, 2, 8, 10, 11};
    selectionSort(arr, size);
    printElement(arr, size);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. You won't always be able to dump your code on another person's lap and ask "tell me what's wrong", and they won't always be able and willing to answer.

Comment: From the looks of it, you want to set `min_id` every time you set `min` but you don't.

Comment: Clearly one problem. No one *calls* this.

Comment: You're not resetting `min_id` on each iteration of the outer loop when you reset `min`.

Comment: Strongly encourage you to task yourself to learn to use the debugger and to turn up the level of compiler errors/warnings to assist you in diagnosing your problems before they happen. From your use of system("PAUSE") you appear to be doing a C++ class with Visual Studio. Right click the project/solution in solution explorer, properties -> C++ -> Warning Level should be 4 or at the very least 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   tmp = arr[i]; //tmp = min; - this is wrong by msl
   arr[i] = arr[min_id]; //min = arr[min_id]; this is wrong by msl
   arr[min_id] = tmp;
```

The above is place in the wrong section of your loop. In selection sort the swapping occurs in the outter loop -- not the inner loop.

Comment: Dear GreatWolf:  your response is correct.  Thank you for you kind and help.  Kelly